# iPhone Safari testing on iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, safari, mobile-safari

I am a web developer, and I have an iPad.  I'd like to be able to see how my websites look on an iPhone too (from my iPad).  Is there an app that allows me to do this?  For example, many iPhone apps, when installed on an iPad run in 320x480 resolution.  The perfect solution would be to be able to install the iPhone version of Safari on my iPad, so I can run it in 320x480 web resolution.  Is anything like this possible?

Yes, I understand I can do this from a computer using an emulator, or use an iPod touch.  I understand there are workarounds, and my question isn't how to test my website for an iPhone...it's how to test it for an iPhone using an iPad.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the perfect solution, but there are iPhone-only browsers that will work on the iPad in *iPhone*-mode.  For instance, the free [Mango Browser](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mango-browser-web-browser/id312259486?mt=8) works well, and seems to present the correct User Agent to sites, so you'll get a fairly good feel for what the experience will be like.  I just tested it on a few sites, and it renders the same as on my iPhone using Safari.

Comment: Although not an exact implementation, this seems to be the best solution as of now.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I would pretty much say that on a non jail-broken iPad you cannot install Safari for iPhone; I can see no way, since installation is so much controlled by Apple.

I have never tried that on a jail-broken iPad, though, but I think that it should be more likely feasible.

Comment: That's pretty much the answer I was expecting.  Thanks for taking the time to respond.